# Capture manually created messages from a function

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, error-handling

My function `foo()` below produces 3 types of messages. Two of them are created by `message()`, and one of them is created by `cat()`.

Suppose I call `foo()` multiple times by `lapply()`.

I want to know `if()` we have any `error message` (the second message that contains the term error) from my `lapply()` call?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use `stop` or `warning`.

```
foo <- function(dat_obj) {
  
  v1 <- sapply(names(dat_obj), function(i) length(unique(dat_obj[[i]])))
  i1 <- names(which(v1 != 1))
  
  if(length(i1) == 1) {
    
    message(paste("Note: potential problem in",i1))
    
  } else if(length(i1) > 1) {
    
    message(paste("Error: fatal problem in x & y."))
    
  } else {
    
    cat(paste("OK: No issues detected.\n"))
  } 
}

#----- EXAMPLE OF USE:
INPUT <- list(
A = data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1), y = c(2,4,3,3)),
B = data.frame(x = c(1,2,1,1), y = c(3,3,3,3)),
C = data.frame(x = c(1,2,1,1), y = c(3,2,3,3)),
D = data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1), y = c(3,3,3,3)))


invisible(lapply(INPUT, foo))
#----- OUTPUT:
#Note: potential problem in y
#Note: potential problem in x
#Error: fatal problem in x & y.
#OK: No issues detected.
```

Comment: Both `message` and `cat` return invisible `NULL`. Maybe try a different logic.

Comment: @RonakShah, I want to know `if()` we have any `error message` (the second message that contains the term `error`) from my `lapply()` call?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, sure like what?

Comment: Like in my answer, or @RonakShah's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions should return something, even if only `invisible(NULL)`. In the case below, I have changed the return value to `NA` assigned to a variable, `y`. Then the logical test numbers, 1, 2, or 3 are an *attribute* of this returned value.

```
foo <- function(dat_obj) {
  v1 <- sapply(names(dat_obj), function(i) length(unique(dat_obj[[i]])))
  i1 <- names(which(v1 != 1))
  if(length(i1) == 1) {
    Attrib <- 1
    message(paste("Note: potential problem in",i1))
  } else if(length(i1) > 1) {
    Attrib <- 2
    message(paste("Error: fatal problem in x & y."))
  } else {
    Attrib <- 3
    cat(paste("OK: No issues detected.\n"))
  }
  y <- NA
  attr(y, "message") <- Attrib
  y
}

invisible(res <- lapply(INPUT, foo))
sapply(res, attr, "message")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `capture.output` to capture the output returned from the function.

```
temp <- capture.output(lapply(INPUT, foo), type = 'message')
temp
#[1] "Note: potential problem in y"   "Note: potential problem in x"   
#    "Error: fatal problem in x & y."
```

To find output where `'Error'` is returned you can use `grep`.

```
grep('Error', temp)
#[1] 3
```